# Using would in the sentences below

Tags: modal-verbs

1. I used to spend hours learning songs on youtube but   would learn nothing.
2. Your movie had an interesting subject, and it did well, but perhaps not as masala (spicy) film would do.
3. You had no advantage then and struggled like any other person would.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see an actual  question.

Answer (score 0):

The word 'Would' can function as:

1. Modal verb
2. Past tense of will
3. Hypothetisis
4. Contingency

The last two reflect  make it function in subjunctive mood.

'Would' functions in:

1. Your first sentence as past tense of 'will'.
2. Your second as subjunctive mood: it's a possibility. The speaker is making a hypothetical assumption.
3. Your third as past tense.

Below are the examples of 'Would' in various instances. Past tense in particular.

*Past Tense*

1. The man left because she would not see him. (Past)
   The action was in the past. See this:

The man will always continue to leave because the estranged wife will never see him. (Future)

*Hypothetical*

1. If I were a girl, I would always wear makeup.

(You can't use 'will' here.) He isn't a girl and will never be one, therefore, it's a hypothetical statement. Only a whimsical wish.

Comment: would as a past tense is confusing for me in most of the sentences but not every sentence.But hypothetical use of 'WOULD' I understand. could you give me some more examples of will as a past tense

Comment: I would also like to ask about first sentence that as a past of will, what is the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: *I used to spend hours learning songs on youtube but would learn nothing.* It's all about the context. For example, in your first sentence: 'Would' is in, context, in past tense because of the word 'used'. The speaker is no longer spending hours on YouTube anymore, perhaps because of frustration, as he wasn't learning anything.

Comment: Hi James, it's really great that you're responding to comments and adding more explanation, but please don't post multiple answers. Use the [edit] button to expand on your existing one. I've merged your two answers into one, and you may want to look over what I did to make sure it's how you would like it. Also, please don't add signatures and other unrelated content - for more information about why, see this discussion : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Thank you very much @collenV. I'm so new here, and I will need every help I can get. I will abide by the rules, and I'll read up the link. Thank you once more.

Comment: Is this  also a Hypothetical question below?                          Use rock salt as you would table.

Comment: No it's not. It's an imperative sentence/independent clause. The speaker is instructing/advising the listener, *Use rock as you would table.

Comment: Is there any difference between: " He doesn't not much & He wouldn't know much.

Comment: I think there is. *He doesn't know much* is affirmative. It means the person doesn't simply know. Whereas, *He wouldn't know much* could either mean the person was unwilling to know more (a past event) or the person can never know much (a firm all-time conclusion of a future event). It depends on the context. For example, **No matter how hard he searches, he would never ever find it.**

Comment: Isn't it a Hypothetical using would in this sense as opposed to doesn't?

Comment: It also could mean that, if, the speaker had an absolute confidence that the person being referred to won't ever know. So, it could be hypothetical, since the speaker might just be saying his own sentiment, it doesn't mean the person won't know. Still, the context is all that matters. @scottish

Comment: I am refering this sentence below, you said that "the speaker is making a hypothetical assumption". Is it making a Hypothetical assumption in the present?                                               "your movie had an interesting subject, and it did well, but perhaps not as masala (spicy) film would do.

Comment: Hi @scottish. I understand you're confused with the use of *Would* in past tense. I will try to explain better in this piece. Some sentences are implicit, meaning that, one would have to study the context before coming to a conclusion. Let's flesh out your example into a conversation. Mr Matthew and Miss Tam are  both movie directors. Tam says to Matt, **"I know you must have seen my movie, what's your say on it, Matt?"**     Matt, with his hands on his white goatee, replies,      **"Your movie had an interesting subject, and it did well, but perhaps not as Masala (spicy) film would do."**

Comment: Here, we see that Matt wasn't dogmatic with his statement, and that's why he used *perhaps.*  If he hadn't used *perhaps,* that might have been on the affirmative. But even without *perhaps,* the context is still hypothetical. The *would* isn't for the Masala film but for Tam's movie, therefore, it's not in the past tense. I am assuming Masala is a big movie, or a big movie producer. Matt is comparing Masala's film with Tam's, he is just **predicting the possible outcome**, therefore, making his statement an assumption.  **Another** usage of *Would*.  @scottish

Comment: If I say, *I would I had gone earlier.* I am saying, *I wish I had gone earlier.* Usually, for *would* to be in past tense, it requires auxiliary modal verbs, *have* and *had*. E.g. *I would have gone.* This obviously can't refer to a future event. 
@scottish

Comment: I have another sentence like this but it is all in present tense, is it similar to above sentence I asked.                They people kill animal in the Jungle,  just as predators do in the Jungle.

Comment: This is in the present. The people still kill animals, they haven't stopped. And till present, and as the norm is, predators would always kill animals in the jungle. But look at this example: **Before the jungle was destroyed by infernos, the people would kill the animals in the jungle, just as the predators did then (I added *then* for emphasis, not really needed).** The *would* here refers to an action which went on for a long time before the sudden termination of the habit by a natural disaster it human-caused fire. Always ask yourself, is this action in the past, or present, or future?

Comment: I am sorry for the sentence above.  the right sentence is "                                                                                       They people kill animal in the Jungle, just as predators would do in the Jungle"